# How to remove data from QTableWidget in pyqt5 in Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a table which has below data:

[image]

I want to remove all the data from the rows and just want to keep the headers i.e. Person Name, Number of Photos Enrolled and Gallery. How can I do this in pyqt5 python. Below is the code I tried but seems not to working:

```
 for item in self.home_ui.show_person_gallery_table.selectedItems():
     new_item = self.home_ui.show_person_gallery_table.item()
     self.home_ui.show_person_gallery_table.setItem(item.row(), item.column(), new_item)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way that you can remove all rows is set table rows count zero like following code.

```
   self.home_ui.show_person_gallery_table.setRowCount(0)
```

for more info about QTableWidget visit this web site https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html

Comment: It gives me this `self.home_ui.show_person_gallery_table.rowCount(0)
TypeError: rowCount(self): too many arguments`

Comment: sorry use 'setRowCount' this function!